# Spring data mongorepository, find by inner object field

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am developing a simple Social network and need help with mongorepository query.
I have 2 documents:

```
@Document(collection = "post")
public class Post {
    ...........
    @DBRef
    @Field("settings")
    private Settings settings;
```

and

```
@Document(collection = "settings")
public class Settings {
    ..............
    @Field("privacy_settings")
    private PrivacySettings privacySettings;
}
```

> PrivacySettings is an enum with settings ONLY_ME, EVERYONE, FRIENDS.

And the situation is: a friend is viewing on my page and he can see my posts with correct privacy settings(etc. he can see only posts with PrivacySettings: EVERYONE, FRIENDS, but not the ONLY_ME).
Ideas, how to resolve this problem? How to create a correct query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution 1** 
In `Mongo`, you can't `query` of `DbRef` fields except for Id as no `join` is supported in this. As `read operation` is very high I will recommend you to `embed` part of `Setting` document in `Post` instead of referencing it. As mongo DB design suggest if `read > write` you should `embed` the document. In this case, the query will be simple.

**Solution 2**
You can fire two DB queries 1st on Setting document to get the `Setting` with `EVERYONE, FRIENDS` the make query on Post document to get all post with Setting `in` query.

**Solution 3** 
You can use `QueryDSL` for query on DbRef object easily [for reference see this.](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/tree/master/querydsl-mongodb)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used Solution2